# Installing Intel 3160 wireless card on embedded computer running 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking

I am attempting to install an Intel 3160 wireless card on an Apalis TK1 embedded computer running Ubuntu 14.04, however I have been unable to connect to any networks. Ubuntu is able to see the card, and the card is able to see the available networks, but it can't make connections.

Network manager can see the device, but the menu is grayed out and listed as "device not ready"

Running `iwlist scan` reports `wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.`, but running `sudo iw dev wlan0 scan` shows the SSIDs in the area.

Here are some command snapshots:

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    9.759415] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.608620.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    9.810273] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[    9.893228] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: 2c:6e:85:55:75:c1
[   10.003470] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
```

and

```
$ modinfo iwlwifi
filename:       /lib/modules/3.10.40-2.8.1+g877a323/updates/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
version:        backported from Linux (v4.14-0-gbebc608) using backports v4.14-rc2-1-34-g1d8cc15
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0--34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-jf-a0--34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-b0--34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-a0--34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-hr-a0--34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-jf-b0--34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-f0-hr-a0--34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0--34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0--34.ucode
srcversion:     9B124ACC35A1F94A98AE124
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002720sv*sd00001080bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002720sv*sd00000070bc*sc*i*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem using the steps described in this link: https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#WPA-PSK_and_WPA2-PSK